How to use _gaq.push in Google Analytics 4
As Google Analytics has now updated to Google Analytics 4, I am wondering how do you configure a _gaq.push(). I am wanting to utilize an anti-adblock (BlockAdBlock.com) but still track it in Google Analytics.
On this website, under the Analytics Integration section it gives an example of
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BlockAdblock', 'Yes', undefined, undefined, true]);

However, all tutorials are outdated for the old Google Analytics. Wondering if someone could assist in helping me figure out how to set a _gaq.push()
